# How can I connect to MongoDB by accepting credentials from user via tkinter

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb, tkinter

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient ('localhost', 27017)
db_label = Label (frame3, text="Database 
                   Name:",padx=5,pady=10).grid(row=1,column=1, sticky=E)
db_name = Entry (frame3, bd=5)
db_name.grid (row=1, column=2)
coll_label = Label (frame3, text="Collection Name:", padx=5, pady=10).grid 
              (row=2, column=1, sticky=E)
coll_name = Entry (frame3, bd=5)
coll_name.grid (row=2, column=2)
db = db_name.get()
collection = coll_name.get()
create_coll = Button (frame3, text="Create Mongo Collection", padx=5, 
pady=10)
create_coll.grid (row=4, column=3)            

db.collection.insertmany(b)
```

How to form a connection URI by accepting the credentials from Tkinter UI?

[image: accept Data base name and table name from user and after clicking on the button create the collection into mongodb]

Comment: and what is the problem ? Do you get error message ? always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: use `Button(..., command=function_name_without_() )` to execute function after clicking button. And inside this function you can get data from `Entry` and use to put data in database.

Comment: you don't have to put space between function/class name and `(`  - ie. `grid(`, `Button(`, `MongoClient(`

Comment: I have edited my post with error message @furas

Comment: @furas spaces are not creating issue . It is the formatting done by pycharm
the query that i have written is not working . I need suggession on that.

Comment: Please don't link to a picture of an error message. Take the time to copy, paste, and format it properly.

Comment: you assign text to `db` in `db = db_name.get()` so why do you use `db.collection. ..` ? maybe you should use `client` for this. Or maybe something like `client[db][collection].insertmany(b)` - check in [pymongo documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have Mongo database to test it, but after checking [pymongo tutorial](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html) I think you need something like this code.

You have to assign function to button and inside this function you get strings from `Entry`s which you have to use as keys in `client["database-name"]["collection-name"]`

**EDIT:** after checking tutorial again I see there should be `insert_many` instead of `insertmany` but I don't have MongoDB to check if it resolves all problems.

```
import tkinter as tk
from pymongo import MongoClient

# --- functions ---

def create():
    db = db_name.get()
    collection = coll_name.get()
    client[db][collection].insert_many("new data")

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)

l = tk.Label(root, text="Database Name:")
l.grid(row=1,column=1)

l = tk.Label(root, text="Collection Name:")
l.grid(row=2, column=1)

db_name = tk.Entry(root)
db_name.grid(row=1, column=2)

coll_name = tk.Entry(root)
coll_name.grid(row=2, column=2)

b = tk.Button(root, text="Create Mongo Collection", command=create)
b.grid(row=4, column=3)            

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @furus
thank you for the reply
I tried this approach and it gives me this error

TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'insertmany' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.

Comment: I don't have MongoDB so I couldn't test it - so I took part of your code and add some elements from tutorial. Now when I check tutorial again I see there is `insert_many`, not `insertmany`.